# Can i run machine learning model using google colab and call the script from google colab to jupyter anaconda?

Tags: python

So i have like a model for energy prediction and I want to run the training in cloud using google colab and then call the model in my local machine using jupyter and run it to make a prediction I wonder if any one have an idea of how I can connect google collab with jupyter

Comment: train the model on clould. download the trained model locally. then test if it works.

Comment: accualy i trained the model using google colab and then saved it in google drive , after that i use google drive API package to get access to the drive and download the file from there and execute it it run well , what i want to do is to make the training automatic when i update the dataset in drive